# How do I Schedule SES mails in JAVA

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, quartz-scheduler, scheduling

is there any API to integrate mails with project for scheduling Amazon web service-Simple Email service

Answer (score 0):

AWS recently announced [support for running Lambda functions](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-lambda-update-python-vpc-increased-function-duration-scheduling-and-more/) written in Java, and for the ability to schedule task execution - sounds like that might fit the bill for you.

Comment: Thanks E.J. Brennan. I will look into it.